# Mysql architecture of log tables

Tags: mysql, logging, architecture

I need 3 tables for logging user activity -> create, login and his device activity.

Is it better to have 1 general table with common columns `(ip, date, type_of_log, external_id_of_log)` and 3 tables with additional data

or

have only 3 tables with same columns (+ additional data) and getting data (ordered by date) thanks to UNION command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you goal is.  A unified (denormalized) table means you will have better performance, at the expense of sparse data (and all the complexity of handling nulls).  A normalized table gives you more concise data, better relational integrity, etc, at the cost of lower performance.

There is no "correct" answer here, it all depends on what you are trying to achieve.  As a default, I usually start with fully normalized tables until I come up with a reason to denormalize.

Comment: Sorry for novice question, but unified result is 4 tables or 3 tables? Thank's a lot.